# Vertically center a fluid image in a fluid container

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I certainly do not want to add to the pile of vertical alignments CSS questions, but I've spent hours trying to find a solution to no avail yet. Here's the situation:

I am building a slideshow gallery of images. I want the images to be displayed as large as the user's window allows. So I have this outer placeholder:

```
<section class="photo full">
```

(Yes, I'm using HTML5 elements). Which has the following CSS:

```
section.photo.full { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

Next, the image is placed inside it. Depending on the orientation of the image, I set either the width or height to 75%, and the other axis to auto:

```
$wide = $bigimage['width'] >= $bigimage['height'] ? true: false; ?>
<img src="<?= $bigimage['url'] ?>" width="<?= $wide? "75%" : "auto"?>" height="<?= $wide? "auto" : "75%"?>"/>
```

So, we have a fluid outer container, with inside a fluid image. The horizontal centering of the image works, yet I cannot seem to find a way to vertically center the image within it's container. I have researched centering methods but most assume either the container or image has a known width or height. Then there is the display:table-cell method, which does not seem to work for me either.

I'm stuck. I'm looking for a CSS solution, but am open to js solutions too.

Comment: @Ferdy Is the SECTION element a direct child of BODY?

Comment: @Ferdy Also, post an sample of the resulting HTML code for the IMG element.

Comment: @Sime: Yes. Hereby a temp demo page: http://ferdy.dnsalias.com/apps/jungledragon/html/tag/92/slideshow/recent/10

Comment: @Ferdy Why do you set `min-height:75%`?

Comment: @Sime. Sorry, I am live developing. I have it removed now. I have this other problem, in IE8 the big image is only 1 pixel high.

Comment: @Ferdy Try using CSS instead: `.class1 { width:75%; height:auto; } .class2 { height:75%; width:auto; }`. Maybe IE likes CSS more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works out fine:

```
section.photo.full {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

section.photo.full a {
  outline: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

section.photo.full img {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

I'm guessing display table-cell hadn't worked for you because it's parent container wasn't displayed as a table.

Here is a demo in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/5wzPS/

Comment: You the man! That indeed works. Still having this other problem with IE8 showing the image only 1 pixel high but thats another challenge to take on.

Comment: By the way, I do notice two side effects afer the fix: 1. the a href seems to have span the width of the entire window instead of 75%. You can see this by hovering next to the image, the cursor will indicate a pointer. 2. when widening the window a lot, a vertical scrollbar appears. It seems the overflow:hidden stopped working :(

Comment: if you are willing to apply an extra div your problem might dissappear: section.photo.full > extradiv > a > img, then apply table-cell to extradiv

Comment: @Duopixel. You rock, dude. That works just great. I now got myself quite a robust slideshow!

Comment: @DuoPixel. Hmmmm, it seems one other issue popped up: overflow:hidden stopped working. This means that scrollbar appears when users resize their window to a certain dimension :( I'm in doubt whether to accept this caveat or to undo the fix. tough call.

Comment: If you don't want scrollbars in any circumstance, then you should apply overflow: hidden to the body. This would fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you (`div` is the div wrapped around your image):

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Running example.](http://jsfiddle.net/FWHXT/)

Comment: The OP said that the container is fluid

Comment: Indeed, the parent container is fluid too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's skip all of the table nonsense! :)

```
<div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x1000">
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/te29m9fv/1/